# ActionServlet - Synchronized block - working of threads

Tags: performance, servlets, synchronization, struts

if there is a `synchronized` block in the `service()` method of say for example in `ActionServlet` of struts, how will multiple requests/threads work if it is a busy site having large number of hits.

Will each thread wait for the next other one to release lock from the synchronized block? Will that create delay in response

Comment: What's the rationale behind this question? Do you have threadsafety issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't synchronize the service method of a servlet.**

If you synchronize the `service` method of a servlet, you are in fact making a "reservation on access" for a thread at a time for that instance of the Servlet.

The Struts `ActionServlet` class is a `HttpServlet` and basically the `doGet` and `doPost` methods are of interest here. If we are to speak about Struts, the [process](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionServlet.html#process%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method is the main entry point, but the same principle applies to all methods as it does for the general `service` method.

The idea is this.

When you declare a servlet in your `web.app`, the servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) will create only one instance of that servlet. This means **there is only one instance to serve all requests**.

If more requests arrive at the same time, each request thread gets it chance at the `service` method because there is no synchronization enforced.

If you have 10 request threads, each will execute concurrently in the `service` method. This is normally safe because processing done in the `service` method does not involve any state related to the current request it is handling. You go into issues if you add state to your servlets. [Here is an article with more details on the subject](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0712-threadsafe.html).

**Now back to Struts**.

Struts uses a pattern called a [Front Controller](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/FrontController.html) with the `ActionServlet` being that controller. This will in turn delegate specific requests to specific `Action` classes as specified in its configuration (a.k.a `struts-config.xml`).

All incoming request pass though here. If you place synchronization at this point (the Struts `process` method or the servlet `service` method higher up) you are reserving the servlet for a thread at a time. **In case of struts, you are reserving all processing of a request to a single thread at a time**.

That means that if 10 request arrive simultaneousely, in the case without synchronization all can execute side by side, while in the case with synchronization request 2 will have to wait until request 1 is done, 3 waits for 2 and so on (i.e. requests are sequentially processed). And this means poor performance.

Maybe for the lucky user that made request 1 there will be no performance impact but number 10 will have to wait. Then how about number 100? 200?

There is no need to synchronize the entry point if you program your application with thread safety in mind. If your application is of the sort that you just can't avoid synchronization, then synchronizing the entry point will reduce performance.

P.S. Just one other thing. If you are thinking into moving the synchronization lower in the process, namely the `Action` classes, note that they are not thread safe either and there is [only one instance of it inside the Struts framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650207/struts-action-singleton/5655287#5655287).

Comment: true, but it's too verbose an answer. I'd suggest putting up the single most important rule on top: don't synchronize servlet methods.