# Why is Struts 2.x made as a multiton? What are the advantages over Struts 1.x?

Tags: web, struts2, struts-1

My team decided to use Struts 2.x but I am confused because Struts 1.x actions are singletons, multi-threaded on the action like servlets. Struts 2.x creates new instances on every request, which increases heap memory usage.

Does using Struts 2.x require more memory?

Comment: Why do you think struts 1.x is a singleton? You are mistaken.

Comment: Main advantage of ThreadLocal actions: you don't have to worry about thread-safety. So buy some RAM and live happy.

Comment: @roman Struts 1.x just extends servlet api....and servlet api is singleton and I saw in the net that struts 1.x is a implementation of singleton pattern

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming No, struts 1.x is not _a implementation of singleton pattern_. It uses many patterns as well as struts 2, the difference is an architecture.

Comment: Hi @Roman C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650207/struts-action-singleton

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming This is different question and *is not* what you meant. Do you think it should be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming The answer is simple: this question can't have a good answer because many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object instantiation in Java is very cheap, so there's no performance problem.

The garbage collector takes care of efficiently reclaiming memory of any objects created during the call, so there's no significant memory impact.

The advantages however are obvious: there's no shared state between requests.